# Microsoft Web App Bot Icon not changing

Tags: botframework

I have changed the icon of my bot in the Bot's Settings. But the new image doesn't appear nor in the Skype for Business neither in the MS Teams conversation.

It is a Web App Bot, created from the template, I went to its blade, settings, and uploaded the less-than-30kb image.
When I go to the conversations in MSTeams and Skype for Business, even 16hs later, it still doesn't display the picture.

Comment: If you are sure that the icon file is valid and legal, but updates can not be reflected on specific channels, you can create [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues) or [contact azure support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to report it.

Comment: I think it's a bug in Azure. Once you upload a icon, you cannot change it due to the "Save" button doesn't work。 I have test it in different subscriptions and resourceGroups, the problem remains.

Comment: I’m able to change the icon. It just doesn’t get reflected on Skype for Business or Slack

Answer (score 2):

The icon should be:

1 **.PNG** image 
2. The resolution should be either **30X30** or **50X50**.

Comment: Where did you find that? I tried with one of 30x29, would that suffice?
I didn't see any impact, is there some time I need to wait?
It looks like within Azure portal I can see the image, like when I go to Channels and try to add a new one there's the Icon I uploaded and an arrow pointing to the logo of the new channel, but still not in Skype for Business.

Comment: Earlier (before 31st March, 2018) in **MS Bot Framework** , you had to register your bot in a portal called dev.botframework.com separately. There, as per the documentation your bot icon should follow the exact two constraints mentioned above. This is a Microsoft Standard for Bot Icons.

Or else, you can try this [hack] (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/43) mentioned here by downloading the **botchat.js**  and **botchat.css** file locally and adding your custom JS and CSS respectively.